# Return id where count of value associated with that id on other table is 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been stuck at a fairly simple scenario but even after scratching my head around for sometime I haven't been able to find a solution... Here's what I have.

I have got 2 tables with following data:

```
Trip (ID, Status)
30063   SUBMITTED
30066   SUBMITTED
30067   ASSIGNED
30068   SUBMITTED
```

And

```
AgentTripAssignment(TripId, AgentId, IsRejected)
30063   5   1
30063   2   0
30066   3   0
30066   4   0
30067   1   0
30067   2   0
30067   3   0
```

What I want to do is:

- Return the trip id from trip table where status is SUBMITTED and if entry for trip is present in other table, count of IsRejected = 1 is zero in the AgentTripAssignment table with 1 query (as new enquiries....30066,30068 in the given case) and
- Return the trip id from trip table where status is SUBMITTED and entry is present in AgentTripAssignment table having count of IsRejected = 1 appearing at least once in the table with second query (as agent rejected....30063 in the given case)

Other point of note is that the status of trip stays SUBMITTED until 3 agents are not assigned to a trip request which is when the status changes to ASSIGNED as is the case with 30067.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:**  Trip Submitted, No 'Rejected' Assignments

This is using a left join on assignments to handle the case of no assignments for a given trip.  If the count of assignments in rejected state is not 0, it's excluded.

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM Trip AS t
LEFT JOIN AgentTripAssignmentx AS at
    ON at.TripId = t.ID
WHERE t.Status = 'SUBMITTED'
GROUP BY t.ID
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN at.IsRejected = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0
```

**Case 2:** Trip Submitted, Has 'Rejected' Assignments

Similar to above, but using an inner join, and excluding trips that don't have assignments rejected.

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM Trip AS t
JOIN AgentTripAssignmentx AS at
    ON at.TripId = t.ID
WHERE t.Status = 'SUBMITTED'
GROUP BY t.ID
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN at.IsRejected = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) > 0
```

Comment: How do you figure?  It's grouping on t.ID.

Comment: Great stuff.....the first part solved my problem...after that i had to do a minor tweaking to the second part to get everything in the right order. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.tripid
from agenttripassignment a
join trip b on a.tripid = b.tripid
where b.status = 'submitted'
group by a.tripid
having max(a.isrejected) = 0
```

and likewise with 1

Comment: Please explain a little. Code only answers are not *good* answers.

Comment: Forgot to tell the datatype of IsRejected column is bit and max operator will not work with bit datatype.

Comment: `having max(a.isrejected+0) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example (in SQL Server syntax) that satisfies your first bullet point.

I broke the query down to try to explain the logic. (first 2 table statements are your data table samples)

```
WITH T AS ( -- Sample data
    SELECT 30063 AS ID, 'Submitted' as Status
    UNION ALL SELECT 30066, 'Submitted'
    UNION ALL SELECT 30067, 'Assigned'
    UNION ALL SELECT 30068, 'Submitted'
), A AS ( -- Sample data
    SELECT 30063 AS ID, 5 AS AgentID, 1 AS IsRejected
    UNION ALL SELECT 30063, 2, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 30066, 3, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 30066, 4, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 30067, 1, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 30067, 2, 0
    UNION ALL SELECT 30067, 3, 0
), TPres AS ( -- get list of all IDs present in A table.
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
    FROM A
), RejCnt AS ( -- get List of all items with a rejected status
    SELECT DISTINCT A.ID
    FROM A
    WHERE IsRejected=1
)
SELECT T.ID
FROM T
    JOIN TPres ON TPres.ID=T.ID -- Filter out where entry for trip is in the other table.
    LEFT JOIN RejCnt ON RejCnt.ID=T.ID -- Used to Determine if IsRejected is Zero
WHERE T.Status='Submitted' -- Where status=Submitted
    AND RejCnt.ID IS NULL -- Has no rejected entries
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simply done with semi-joins (joins that filter rows but do not provide access to data and do not cause duplication of rows). For your first request, here is an anti-semi-join:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
   dbo.Trip T
WHERE
   T.Status = 'SUBMITTED'
   AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.AgentTripAssignment AT
      WHERE
         T.ID = AT.TripId
         AND AT.IsRejected = 1
   )
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7870/1)

This is very simply read as, "show me all rows from table `Trip` where no matching row (based on ID) exists in table `AgentTripAssignment` that has `IsRejected = 1`".

For your second query, it is almost exactly the same, simply change `AND NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS`: "show all rows from table `Trip` where at least one matching row (based on ID) exists in table `AgentTripAssignment` that has `IsRejected = 1`".

The reason I prefer the `EXISTS` semi-join syntax is that it can often be better performance, depending on the exact indexes. It also helps database developers think in ways that I think are beneficial. It also has the benefit of not having to tack on a `DISTINCT` to fix duplication, and it avoids the problems of an aggregate method by allowing you to return all rows from the desired table (when a `GROUP BY` would have to contain all the columns in the table).